# why these two java.util.Pattern are not equal

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have two regular expressions using java.util.regex.Pattern.compile. The first one is:

```
input[\\s\\w=:'\\-"]*type\\s*=\\s*['"]password['"];
```

the second one is:

```
input[\\s\\w=:'\\-\\\"]*type\\s*=\\s*['\\\"]password['\\\"];
```

The only difference between these two regexes is escaping double quotations in the latter string. " and \" refer to the same ASCII character ", so they get same matching results.

However, when I do the following code, it returns False.

```
Pattern p1=Pattern.compile("input[\\s\\w=:'\\-"]*type\\s*=\\s*['"]password['"]");
Pattern p2=Pattern.compile("input[\\s\\w=:'\\-\\\"]*type\\s*=\\s*['\\\"]password['\\\"]");
System.out.println(p1.equals(p2));
```

Comment: The first line will not compile because of unescaped `"` so it can't return anything as it can't run. Post proper example which will let us reproduce your problem.

Comment: `Pattern.equals` does not actually test if the regular expressions are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 8 `Pattern` class doesn't override `equals`. So it uses default implementation which checks whether to references point to the same location in memory.